# How to count property different values in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting a json objects from database. What is the Best practice to count number of `ClassDef` values `A , B , C`.
In the json object for eg: I have in this json " 2 A and 2 B and 3 c "

My json object:

```
[{
    "ItemCode": "200500303800356",
    "LastCost": 8,
    "OnHand": 593889,
    "InventoryValue": 4751112,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 18.294517,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 18.29,
    "ClassDef": "A"
}, {
    "ItemCode": "201600701800197",
    "LastCost": 400,
    "OnHand": 300,
    "InventoryValue": 120000,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 0.462069,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 75.68,
    "ClassDef": "A"
}, {
    "ItemCode": "200701507000107",
    "LastCost": 75,
    "OnHand": 239,
    "InventoryValue": 17925,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 0.069022,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 91.75,
    "ClassDef": "B"
}, {
    "ItemCode": "200501303400308",
    "LastCost": 3515,
    "OnHand": 5,
    "InventoryValue": 17575,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 0.067674,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 91.81,
    "ClassDef": "B"
}, {
    "ItemCode": "200200106701035",
    "LastCost": 80,
    "OnHand": 27,
    "InventoryValue": 2160,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 0.008317,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 99.28,
    "ClassDef": "C"
}, {
    "ItemCode": "200200902700248",
    "LastCost": 10,
    "OnHand": 213,
    "InventoryValue": 2130,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 0.008202,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 99.29,
    "ClassDef": "C"
}, {
    "ItemCode": "200601302001093",
    "LastCost": 0.3,
    "OnHand": 6,
    "InventoryValue": 1.8,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 0.000007,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 100,
    "ClassDef": "C"
}]
```

Does any have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Which language are you looking to do this in - JS or Java?

Comment: which value do you loke to count? just how many occurences or a special value?

Comment: Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) method

Comment: i am trying to do it in js

Comment: Not sure to well understand your demand. You want to count the number of `ClassDef` in your whole array ? Or the number of value that contains `ClassDef` in a single object ?

Comment: number of each value of ClassDef for eg i have in this json example" 2 A and 2 B and 3 c "

Comment: Oh ok! You must write an example in your question, this isn't easy to understand

Comment: ok i am sorry i will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object for the result and use `ClassDef` as key.

```js
var data = [{ ItemCode: "200500303800356", LastCost: 8, OnHand: 593889, InventoryValue: 4751112, PercOfTotalInventory: 18.294517, CumerativePercTotal: 18.29, ClassDef: "A" }, { ItemCode: "201600701800197", LastCost: 400, OnHand: 300, InventoryValue: 120000, PercOfTotalInventory: 0.462069, CumerativePercTotal: 75.68, ClassDef: "A" }, { ItemCode: "200701507000107", LastCost: 75, OnHand: 239, InventoryValue: 17925, PercOfTotalInventory: 0.069022, CumerativePercTotal: 91.75, ClassDef: "B" }, { ItemCode: "200501303400308", LastCost: 3515, OnHand: 5, InventoryValue: 17575, PercOfTotalInventory: 0.067674, CumerativePercTotal: 91.81, ClassDef: "B" }, { ItemCode: "200200106701035", LastCost: 80, OnHand: 27, InventoryValue: 2160, PercOfTotalInventory: 0.008317, CumerativePercTotal: 99.28, ClassDef: "C" }, { ItemCode: "200200902700248", LastCost: 10, OnHand: 213, InventoryValue: 2130, PercOfTotalInventory: 0.008202, CumerativePercTotal: 99.29, ClassDef: "C" }, { ItemCode: "200601302001093", LastCost: 0.3, OnHand: 6, InventoryValue: 1.8, PercOfTotalInventory: 0.000007, CumerativePercTotal: 100, ClassDef: "C" }],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        r[o.ClassDef] = (r[o.ClassDef] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to find how many times

- *ClassDef* equals *C*
- *ClassDef* equals *C* or *B*

```js
var arr=[{ItemCode:"200500303800356",LastCost:8,OnHand:593889,InventoryValue:4751112,PercOfTotalInventory:18.294517,CumerativePercTotal:18.29,ClassDef:"A"},{ItemCode:"201600701800197",LastCost:400,OnHand:300,InventoryValue:12e4,PercOfTotalInventory:.462069,CumerativePercTotal:75.68,ClassDef:"A"},{ItemCode:"200701507000107",LastCost:75,OnHand:239,InventoryValue:17925,PercOfTotalInventory:.069022,CumerativePercTotal:91.75,ClassDef:"B"},{ItemCode:"200501303400308",LastCost:3515,OnHand:5,InventoryValue:17575,PercOfTotalInventory:.067674,CumerativePercTotal:91.81,ClassDef:"B"},{ItemCode:"200200106701035",LastCost:80,OnHand:27,InventoryValue:2160,PercOfTotalInventory:.008317,CumerativePercTotal:99.28,ClassDef:"C"},{ItemCode:"200200902700248",LastCost:10,OnHand:213,InventoryValue:2130,PercOfTotalInventory:.008202,CumerativePercTotal:99.29,ClassDef:"C"},{ItemCode:"200601302001093",LastCost:.3,OnHand:6,InventoryValue:1.8,PercOfTotalInventory:7e-6,CumerativePercTotal:100,ClassDef:"C"}];

function countOccurences(name, value) {
  var count = 0;
  // If name and values are defined
  if (name && value) {
    // Check either a single value or an array of values
    var values = (value instanceof Array ? value : [value])
    // For each object in array
    arr.forEach(function(v) {
      // If values array contains object[name] value
      if (v[name] && values.indexOf(v[name]) !== -1) {
        // Increment counter
        count++;
      }
    });
  }
  return count;
}

console.log("ClassDef === 'C' :", countOccurences("ClassDef", "C"));
console.log("ClassDef === 'C' or 'B' :", countOccurences("ClassDef", ["C", "B"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Through some clever use of [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) this is a piece of cake.

```
const objArray = [{
    "ItemCode": "200500303800356",
    "LastCost": 8,
    "OnHand": 593889,
    "InventoryValue": 4751112,
    "PercOfTotalInventory": 18.294517,
    "CumerativePercTotal": 18.29,
    "ClassDef": "A"
}, ...];

const classDefSet = objArray.reduce((set, obj) => {
    set.add(obj.ClassDef); // add value to the set. If it already exists nothing will happen
    return set;
}, new Set());

const count = [...classDefSet].length; // convert set to plain array
console.log(count); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `reduce` example:

```js
let arr = [{
"ItemCode": "200500303800356",
"LastCost": 8,
"OnHand": 593889,
"InventoryValue": 4751112,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 18.294517,
"CumerativePercTotal": 18.29,
"ClassDef": "A"
}, {
"ItemCode": "201600701800197",
"LastCost": 400,
"OnHand": 300,
"InventoryValue": 120000,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 0.462069,
"CumerativePercTotal": 75.68,
"ClassDef": "A"
 }, {
"ItemCode": "200701507000107",
"LastCost": 75,
"OnHand": 239,
"InventoryValue": 17925,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 0.069022,
"CumerativePercTotal": 91.75,
"ClassDef": "B"
 }, {
"ItemCode": "200501303400308",
"LastCost": 3515,
"OnHand": 5,
"InventoryValue": 17575,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 0.067674,
"CumerativePercTotal": 91.81,
"ClassDef": "B"
 },  {
"ItemCode": "200200106701035",
"LastCost": 80,
"OnHand": 27,
"InventoryValue": 2160,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 0.008317,
"CumerativePercTotal": 99.28,
"ClassDef": "C"
 }, {
"ItemCode": "200200902700248",
"LastCost": 10,
"OnHand": 213,
"InventoryValue": 2130,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 0.008202,
"CumerativePercTotal": 99.29,
"ClassDef": "C"
 },  {
"ItemCode": "200601302001093",
"LastCost": 0.3,
"OnHand": 6,
"InventoryValue": 1.8,
"PercOfTotalInventory": 0.000007,
"CumerativePercTotal": 100,
"ClassDef": "C"
}];

let result = arr.reduce((acc, el)=>{
  if (el.hasOwnProperty("ClassDef")){
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(el.ClassDef)){
      acc[el.ClassDef] = 0;
    }
    acc[el.ClassDef]++;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may useful for you. you can count the values assigned to the key "ClassDef" as show here [the count of the duplicate value assigned to the same key in JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858488/how-to-get-the-count-of-duplicate-value-assigned-to-same-key-in-json-array-jav)

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample json object, try this :

```
var countArr = [];
for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    var val =  obj[i]["ClassDef"];
    if(countArr[val] != null)
    {
        countArr[val] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        countArr[val] = 1;
    }

}
```

this will return you

```
[A: 2, B: 2, C: 3]
```